# Highchart's error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So What I am trying to do is that I am trying to create Plotline on a particular X value based on the data I have in an array.

There are 2 data arrays that I have :

```
 featurex = [95,193,295,393,480,587,700,799,912,1015,1123,1230,1336,1443,1554] ;
 featurey = [0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
```

Now What I am trying to do is that I am trying to Plot a plotline on X-axis where my Y-axis is 3 As you can see above.

I am able to do it statically, but I want it to be dynamic.

This is the Highchart's code that I am using.

```
Highcharts.chart('ppg', {
    chart: {
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'ECG Data'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: ''
    },
    xAxis: 

       for( i=0; i<featurex.length; i++)
     {
        if (featurey[i] == 3) {
            plotLines: [

                   {
                        value: featurex[i],
                        color: '#005a9b94',
                        dashStyle: 'shortdash',
                        width: 100,
                    },

        }


      },
      crosshair: false

    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Peaks'

        }
    },
   tooltip: {
        enable: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: '',
        lineWidth: 2,
        data: yData,
         animation: {
                duration: 5000
            }
         },
   {    type: 'scatter',
        name: 'Installation',
        data: zip(xPeak, yPeak),
        animation: {
                duration: 5200
            }
      },



     ]
});

});

});
</script>
```

Here the Plotline code under the `Xaxis` is the main area of concern. 
It's throwing me an error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token for

Please guide me on what I am doing wrong.

Any Help is really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: your error message is incomplete. and your Hex code for color is more than 6 characters. my guess is your error is around that for-loop. remove and put an array and test again

Comment: that's the only error message in the console. its pointing towards the error of for loop. and as far as the HEX code goes, the last two digits represent the opacity. @muzijack

Comment: Do not use for loops inside js objects. Instead, use a function that will return a plotLines array. Check the @cdoshi answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here,

```
xAxis: 
    for( i=0; i<featurex.length; i++)
```

Above is not valid javascript syntax.

If you need plotlines to be dynamic, pass a function that returns an array

```
xAxis: {
  plotLines: generateDynamicPlotLines(),
}
```

And your function would be something like,

```
function generateDynamicPlotLines() {
    const plotLines = [];
    for(var i=0; i<featurex.length; i++) {
       if (featurey[i] == 3) {
           plotLines.push({
           value: featurex[i],
           color: '#005a9b94',
           dashStyle: 'shortdash',
           width: 100,
       });
     }
   }
   return plotLines;
}
```

Comment: The Exact solution I was looking for, Thanks a lot. Appreciated.

Comment: Glad to be of help!!

Answer (score 0):

Seems your `plotLines` assignment is missing a `]` in your code, it should have been like this,

```
plotLines: [{
          value: featurex[i],
          color: '#005a9b94',
          dashStyle: 'shortdash',
          width: 100,
      }],
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried this. but the code still has the same error

Comment: Can you please put your (or a working code) in jsfiddle and share me the link to debug more?